# Service not saving SharedPreference for Main Activity?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-service

I am using a service to download and retrieve a list of URL's and put them in a sharedpreference.

With this..

```
SharedPreference images_article = this.getSharedPreferences("images_articles", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
editor.putString("article2", urlImage2);
editor.putString("article3", urlImage2);
editor.commit();
```

Then in my Main.Activity i pull the url's from preference.

```
SharedPreference images_article = this.getSharedPreferences("images_articles",  MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
urlImage2 = images_article.getString("article2", "NO ARTICLE AVAILABLE");
urlImage3 = images_article.getString("article3", "NO ARTICLE URL AVAILABLE");
```

The only problem is for some reason it isnt going inside of the shared preference, because the Main activity is loading the OLD URL's that has now changed. But in the Service i log the url's being retrieved and they are updated but for some reason in the main activity it still loads the old one. and im retrieving them from the same preference.

Is there anything i am missing or a better way to do this? Any help would be great!!

Comment: How are you obtaining the `editor` object?

Answer (score 4):

I was running in to a similar issue with my SharedPreferences between my Activity and Service. I ended up not using the default and used my own set file name

in the activity and service I set

```
private static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "MyPreferenceFileName";
```

Then to get the values:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref_checked = pref.getBoolean("checked", true);
```

and to set the values:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checked", value);
editor.commit();
```

This allowed me to use the same get and put logic in both my Service and Activity without any issues.  I hope this helped.

Comment: While this might work, it is possible to use default Shared Preferences across and activity and service. Default SPs just use a particular name - there's nothing special about them.

Comment: Agreed here with @DavidCaunt. I running on similar problem and it seems to be a problem about timing. My main activity that uses a value of the setup get the old value several times, but when there is any resume of it, it gets the right value. I believe my main activity reads the SP before the other one saves it or it caches the values somehow. 

Someone has any idea? I try to get the value on the resume method.

Answer (score 2):

This might be happening due to the different contexts you are accessing from. I am not very sure though, but you can try this :

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
```

Use this code, whenever you try to access `SharedPreferences`, that is, from both the `Service` and the `Activity`. That might solve your problem.

Comment: Ran into this issue with an activity and service running on Android Wear. For some reason the SharedPreferences object was different in the service and activity. The solution above fixed the problem. I'm not sure why the context was different.

Answer (score 1):

Using this in both the Activity and Service classes seems to work for me, as it should now be using the same Context to access the application SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```